About hypothesis on the limit of differentiability of a series of functions.
Here is the statement :

Let $E$ and $F$ be finite dimensional normed vector space ($\dim >1$). Let us
consider $(f_k)$ a sequence of functions which are differentiable on
$U \subset E$ open.
Suppose : $(i)$ the series $\left(\sum f_k\right)$ converges uniformly
to $g$ on every compact set of $U$,
and $(ii)$ for every compact $K\subset U$, $\sum \sup\limits_{x\in K}
 \Vert (\mathrm{d}f_k)(x) \Vert < +\infty$, where $\Vert.\Vert$ stands
for the operator norm.
Then $g$ is differentiable on $U$ and $\mathrm{d}g = \mathrm{d} \left(
 \sum_k f_k\right)= \sum_k \mathrm{d}f_k$.

I was wondering if the hypothesis $(i)$ was too strong because in general we us the point wise convergence of $\left(\sum f_k\right)$ on at least one point of $U$.
Moreover, The hypothesis $(ii)$ implies the uniform convergence of the series of the derivatives and then we re-find the second hypothesis of the classical theorem.
Thanks in advance !
